# INSERT INTO SELECT causing data to double

Tags: teradata

I have strange issue. I am working in a Teradata database.
In a procedure I am populating a main table by processing data via multiple intermediate tables.
But in the end only one table is populating the main table.
The syntax is something like this

```
INSERT INTO sch_1.main_table
(
col1,
col2...
coln
)
SELECT
col1,
col2...
coln
FROM sch_1.work_table;
```

Now the `count(*) from sch_1.work_table` results in `112`rows whereas its going straight to double in `sch_1.main_table` i.e. `224` rows.

I am unable to share the logic of the procedure as its for a client.
But this thing has me stumped. 
There are no joins involved in this statement, just a plain and simple insert from a work table to a main table.

Has anyone faced this?

Comment: Doubling the number of row is impossible unless the insert runs twice (and the table is MultiSet without any Uniqueness constraint). Can you get details from QueryLog?

Comment: Getting result from QueryLog won't be possible since we are not logging the session in which it is running. Also we are unable to replicate the same issue in the test environment. It's just happening in one production environment. The table is multiset with a primary index defined on it.

Comment: I wonder how it's possible to have a unique index and duplicate rows in a table.

Comment: Exactly why it has me stumped..

Comment: A *Primary Index*  in Teradata is similar to a *clustered index*, but not the same as a *Primary Key* (unless it's a *Unique Primary Index*).

Comment: Have you done a double MINUS of both tables?

Comment: No, its a simple INSERT-SELECT statement

Comment: Rob probably meant to check the output from `sel * from A minus sel * from B` and the other way around - to see if there are any difference between the data in the two tables or if it's just duplicates. If we're talking duplicates, I'd try setting up a UPI on the target table and see which step fails the uniqueness check.

Answer (score 1):

Might be caused by a trigger on the target table

Answer (score 0):

I am new to sql but try SELECT DISTINCT instead of just SELECT. It worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, but that way you wont find out **why** this inserts double data rows. Nevertheless, it's certainly a valid answer :-)

Comment: @til_b: I disagree. If the OP says the row count obtained directly from the source is correct and the SELECT part of the INSERT statement contains no joins, there's no way the SELECT itself is responsible for the doubling of rows. The issue must be somewhere else. Therefore, nothing prevents SELECT DISTINCT from inserting the double number of rows just as well as the simple SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try just using a SELECT INTO syntax instead of using the fully specified INSERT INTO.  That would eliminate any potential mismatch between the two statements.  So you'd just do this:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2...
    coln
INTO sch_1.main_table
FROM sch_1.work_table;
```

Comment: This works only if the target table doesnt exist